# background coursel comes on bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I encountered a problem working on my web app. bootstrap modal works very bad and background pace Coursera icon comes on top of modal.
this is error [image](http://www.mediafire.com/view/lgjeih6gqccq16b/error.JPG)

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: try to add this class into your css at bottom `.modal{z-index:9999999}`

Comment: Learner: thank you, Your solution was perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The `z-index` Solution:

The CSS `z-index` property specifies which element will stay at the top if they overlap each other. The Bootstrap modal probably has a lower (or set to default) `z-index` than your carousel. So the carousel navigation button is overlapping the modal.

To fix this, try adding the following CSS at the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
.modal {
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

This basically sets the `z-index` of the modal to a much higher value than the carousel.

**References:**

- **http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp**
- **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index**
- **https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/**